# Accepting gmail invite in Outlook 2016

Tags: microsoft-outlook, sync, google-calendar

I am working with a user who has Outlook 2016 (local copy) on her laptop synced to her gmail account.  When she receives and event invitation in email and accepts it, the event is stored on her (cloud) Google calendar, and not in any of the local calendars in Outlook.  Is there any way to cause the accepted event to be stored in a local calendar?

I know I could sync local Outlook to the online google calendar, and that is an option if no direct solution is found.  The whole setup is already synced to iCloud in order to get it on to an iPhone.

(Yes, I know the better approach is to move the whole setup to Google (or Outlook online), but there is a large set of needed historical information in Outlook (PC), so local Outlook will remain part of the setup anyway.)

Is there any way to get those calendar acceptances to show up in the local calendar?

Comment: "Is there any way to cause the accepted event to be stored in a local calendar?" - Google discontinued support for that a number years ago on the free Google Mail accounts.

Comment: I thought I saw that Google had a sync application that they discontinued, but is there no other solution?  And, in any event, why does the acceptance have to go back to Google at all?  The invite is in the local calendar, the click to accept is in the local calendar - isn't there a way to direct Outlook to store the result locally?  I'm not trying to sync - I don't care if there is NO record of the event in Google calendar.